# API or any other way to get heap size of Kafka server using Java program

Tags: java, spring-kafka

Is there a way to get total heap size, free heap size of a Kafka server? 
I am trying to avoid OutOfMemory error with the help of heap size.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor memory with JMX. It's an API that exposes MBeans, Managed Beans. In your case, you need to monitor this MBean [MemoryMXBean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html)

If you don't know how to set up JMX, you may need to take a look at some tutorials online like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html.

By the way, Kafka exposes a lot of JMX metrics you may want to monitor too. You can find all of them [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/monitoring.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how can I know that MemoryMXBean will return kakfa heap size and not the application heap size.

Comment: A best practice is to separate the Kafka server machine from application machine. In this way, any problem from one machine will not impact others and your metrics are clearly isolated.